# Gettext translate string with link

Tags: php, gettext, translate

I have a string I'd like to translate with gettext that looks like this:

```
Check your email for an order confirmation or <a href="some_link">click here</a> to see your orders.
```

What would be the best way to wrap this into gettext? My current way, using `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(_('Check your email for an order confirmation or %s to see your orders.'), '<a href="' . route('user.orders') . '">' . _('click here') . '</a>'))
```

However, I imagine the translator thinking:

> What the **** is this string: "Check your email for an order confirmation or SOMETHING to see your orders." What is SOMETHING?

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder like this:

```
"Check your email for an order confirmation or _ClickHere_ to see your orders"
```

Or even: `_ClickHereLink_`.

It's meaningful for the translator and easy to pick up with `str_replace`.

*Only thing you need to do is tell translator not to translate your placeholders - I've seen people doing that ;)*